# If three cards are drawn from a standard deck, what is the probability of drawing a $10, J, Q$ in that order with replacement? without replacement?

Tags: probability

If I get to draw $3$ cards from a standard deck.

With replacement - a) What is the probability of drawing a $10,J,Q$ in that order?

Without replacement - b) What is the probability of drawing a $10,J,Q$ in that order?

With replacement - c) Drawing at least one ace (I got $= \left(\frac{4}{52}\right)^3$).

Without replacement - d) Drawing at least one ace (I got $= \left(\frac{4}{52}\right)\left(\frac{3}{51}\right)\left(\frac{2}{50}\right)$)

Having trouble with a) and b) I know that order matters so I would have to use combinations.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) In other words, it must be the case that you get a 10, then a J, then a Q. Since the draws are *with* replacement, then the probabilities don't change and the draws are independent from one another (assuming the deck is shuffled after replacement). 
Then we have
$$P(TJQ) = P(T)P(J)P(Q) = \frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{4}{52}.$$

b) Again, it must be the case that you get a 10, then a J, then a Q. Since the draws are *without* replacement, then the probabilities do change and the draws are not independent from one another.  After each draw, the number of cards in deck reduces by one, and hence
$$P(TJQ) = \frac{4}{52}\cdot \frac{4}{51}\cdot\frac{4}{50}.$$

c) No, what you calculated is the chance that you got exactly 3 Aces (or really any rank) in three draws with replacement.

A direct calculation involves find the chance of an Ace in the first or second or third draw and using inclusion exclusion.

Alternatively, we can use the complement: No Aces in three draws. This is equal to $(48/52)^3$. Hence
$$P(\text{At least one Ace}) = 1-P(\text{No Aces}) = 1-\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^3.$$

d) Again, we use the complement. There are $48$ Non Aces, and in three draws we must draw a non Ace. After each draw, the number of non Aces goes down, and so
$$P(\text{At least one Aces})=1- P(\text{No Aces}) = 1-\frac{48}{52}\cdot\frac{47}{51}\cdot\frac{46}{50}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Some useful hints:

**Ad a)** The probability that the first card is a 10 is $\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}$. You have four 10´s and 52 cards in total. Similar probabilities for $J$ and $Q$.

**Ad b)** The probability that the first card is a 10 is $\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}$. But then the probability that the next card is a J is $\frac{4}{52-1}$, because the remaining cards have been reduced by one card.

**Ad c)** Here you can calculate by using the converse probability. The probability to draw at least on ace is equal to One minus the probability to draw no ace: $P(\texttt{"at least one ace"})=1-P(\texttt{"no ace"})$

**Ad d)** Same idea like in c), but without replacement. $P(\texttt{"First card no ace")}=\frac{48}{52}$, $P(\texttt{"Second card no ace")}=\frac{48-1}{52-1}=\frac{47}{51}$ and so on.